# Get length of a pointer ( not sizeoff )

Tags: c, pointers

For some special reason I need to get the length (in character) of a pointer.
If the pointer is :

```
0x2ADF4
```

It should return `5`, 
because there are 5 characters in the pointer.
In fact I want the length of the hexadecimal representation of the pointer casted as an integer.
 This number should vary from pointer to pointer.
Please note I do not want the total memory occupation my pointer (which I can get via sizeoff).

Comment: Also, why is that pointer `0x0ADF4` and not `0x0000ADF4` or `0xADF4`? That's totally up to the (arbitrarily) chosen format.

Comment: Why is there a leading zero? Shouldn't the "length" of this value be 4? And why "should" it vary between pointers?

Comment: Yes you're right about the leading 0, I modified the post

Comment: That's not "the lenght of the pointer". That's the "length of the hexadecimal representation of the pointer casted as an integer".

Comment: yes you are right, i will modify the post

Comment: But what is your "special reason" to want that. Looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. You should **edit your question** to motivate it!

Comment: @leonbloy  That's the "length of the hexadecimal representation of the pointer casted as an integer" + "with leading zeros removed". Which is unusual, normally pointers are presented with all digits present

Comment: Note that "the length of the hexadecimal representation of the pointer casted as an integer" in the edited version of the question actually is an answer.

Comment: Presumably you're outputting some table of pointer values, but there are much better ways to achieve textual alignment with data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast the ptr to type `intptr_t` and from there use a standard digit counting algorithm :

```
int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    int* ptr = &counter;
    intptr_t val = (intptr_t)ptr; 

    while ( val > 0 )
    {
        val/=16;
        ++counter;
    }

    printf("%d", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried with this actual code, my ptr is `"0028FF34"` and the output is `6`

Comment: @Badda That's how numbers work :p The leading 0's are purely down to formatting and do not represent any difference in actual value (looking at the comments, the op seems to want leading 0's removed).

Comment: You should probably cast it to an `intptr_t` instead. I'm not sure if the standard says anything about `sizeof(size_t)` vs `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: @Kevin Just had a quick look and I couldn't find anything to suggest that `sizeof(size_t)` is guaranteed to be equivalent to `sizeof(int*)`, so i've updated the answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

So you want the length of some *textual representation* of your pointer (beware of the terminology, your don't want the size of the allocated memory zone holding that pointer), often of a pointer into some [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) memory location (but perhaps not).

You should notice that both [`sprintf` and `snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) are returning the number of bytes written to some buffer (including the terminating zero byte) and they both accept a `NULL` buffer, so you could code:

```
int ptrtextlen = sprintf(NULL, "%p", ptr);
```

In your case (for `ptr` being 0x2ADF4), it would return 8 (because `0x2ADF4` needs 7 bytes starting with `0` and `x` up to `4`, and one additional terminating zero byte). BTW, read more about `sprintf` (you may use it to get some leading zeros, but you'll probably need to cast the `ptr` to `long` or more probably `uintptr_t`)

<sup>(AFAIK, the C11 standard does not guarantee any specific textual representation of pointer with `%p` - they are implementation specific; I'm thinking of my Linux/x86-64 desktop)</sup>

If you want the length of some null terminated string (given by the pointer to its first character) use [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

> I do not want the total memory occupation my pointer (which I can get via sizeof)

This is very wrong. All pointers have the same `sizeof` (independently of the size of the pointed memory), which is 8 bytes on my Linux/x86-64 machine; so for example

```
 char buf[32];
 int ptrtextlen = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%p", ptr);
 printf("ptrtextlen=%d length(buf)=%zd\n", ptrtextlen, strlen(buf));
```

should output `ptrtextlen=6 length(buf)=5` on my Linux/x86-64 desktop

```
int*heaptr = malloc(1024*sizeof(int));
printf("%zd", sizeof(heaptr));
```

will output 8 (not 4096, which is the byte size of the memory zone given by the *successful* call to `malloc`, since `sizeof(int)` is 4 on my machine).

PS. Spend several days reading more about [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) and its [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) specification; it looks that you are *very confused*. Read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Answer (score -2):

The size of a pointer will depend on the architecture of the machine such that a 32bit system will have their pointers as 4 bytes in memory and a 64bit system will have it as 8 bytes in memory. These sizes will not change on a particular system. Knowing this will help you to design the needed algorithm. Your function or method should first check to see what the size of a pointer is for the particular machine. Once you know the size of the pointer the next step would be to check to see if it is little endian or big endian. Once you are able to determine which endian is being used then you can begin to design your algorithm. After you know what these two are then you should be able to store the actual physical address into a character array. From there you can then strip out all non significant leading zeros leaving you with any characters that are non zero and save them into a new dynamic character array. I would suggest using unsigned char for this. Then it is a matter of counting how many bytes are in the unsigned character array that you just extrapolated from the original address. Note if the address is in hex value then every 2 characters is 1 byte. So if the resulting character array has 8 values then there is 4 bytes; but you would want to return 8 as in the length and not 4 as in bytes.

**EDIT** - Pseudo Code

```
unsigned getAddressLength( unsigned char& address ) {
    // First Check to See if System is 16bit, 32bit, 64bit etc.
    unsigned sizeInBytes = sizeof( address );

    bool isBigEndian;

    // test if Big or Little Endian;
    if ( address is Big ) {
        isBigEndian = true;
    } else {
        isBigEndian = false;
    }

    unsigned char[] addressBytes; // Evert 2 Characters In The Address String is 1 byte of memory.
    if ( isBigEndian ) {
         // Perform Algorithm This Way To Strip Out Non Significant 0s
    } else {
         // Same Thing But For Little Endian
    }

    // After Striping out All Non Significant leading 0s get the size in bytes of this new array

    return (new length of character array);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have the OP asked the length of the address. In order to know the length you need to know the size first because of different architectures, and knowing the endian is important too because of the byte ordering. Then it is a matter of stripping out the non significant leading 0s and storing the result into a new character array. The size or length of this character array will be the length of the pointer address the OP is looking for since every two non 0 characters represents one byte of memory addressing. I did make a single mistake; if the address is in hex; each 2 characters is 1 byte